# Windows Authentication to Access SQL Server from my application

Tags: sql-server, windows, security

I have 2 applications, one is written in vb6 and the other is asp.net web application.
from both of them I'd like to connect a remote (but on the same network) sql server 2008 r2 database.
Somehow, this doesn't work. I wanna put the asp.net application aside for now and just test the vb6 one.
The strange things is, if i install sql management studio on the same machine where
my vb6 application is installed and try to connect my remote sql server using windows authontication it works.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: "Somehow, this doesn't work" - does not constitute a real question.

Comment: Actually I'm looking for some information on what are the security issues i need to look for in my sql server, i assume it's there because the same settings work on different configuration (different sql server etc).

Answer (score 0):

A shot in the dark: 2008R2 is much newer than vb6. What type of data connectivity are you using in the vb6 app?